# Saving content of a webpage using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape a webpage using BeautifulSoup using the code below:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with urllib.request.urlopen("http://en.wikipedia.org//wiki//Markov_chain.htm") as url:
    s = url.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(s)

with open("scraped.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    f.write(soup.get_text())
    f.close()
```

The problem is that it saves the [Wikipedia's main page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page) instead of that specific article. Why the address doesn't work and how should I change it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct url for the page is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain:

```
>>> import urllib.request
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> url = "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url))
>>> soup.title
<title>Markov chain - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</title>
```

Comment: Just for clarify: the reason Wikipedia directs the OP's URL to the main page is that extra slash at the beginning. Everything between the first two slashes (after the hostname) selects the wiki namespace, and since the namespace `//` doesn't exist, it just gives up and redirects you to the front page. (The `.htm` at the end would just download a page asking whether you wanted to create an article named "Markov chain.htm"…)

Comment: @abarnert thank you for the note, good detailed explanation, as usual.

Comment: How can get the whole page, not just the title?

Answer (score 0):

**@alecxe's answer will generate:**

```
**GuessedAtParserWarning**: 
No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best 
available HTML parser for this system ("html.parser"). This usually isn't a problem, 
but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it 
may use a different parser and behave differently. The code that caused this warning
is on line 25 of the file crawl.py. 

To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html.parser"' to
the BeautifulSoup constructor.
```

Here is a **solution without GuessedAtParserWarning** using `requests`:

```
# crawl.py

import requests

url = 'https://www.sap.com/belgique/index.html'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

file = path.join(path.dirname(__file__), 'downl.txt')

# Either print the title/text or save it to a file
print(soup.title)
# download the text
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(soup.text)
```